# Generating QR-code in header impossible?

Tags: header-footer, pstricks, fancyhdr, auto-pst-pdf, pst-barcode

I've got a strange issue with the packages `pstricks`/`pst-barcode` and `fancyhdr`.
Here is what I like to do: A custom header for every page, Name on the left, QR-code on the right.

Although the QR-code generated without any problems when I first tested it inside the page, it won't do if I put it into fancyheader. Although I searched and tried to find some solution for the last few hours, but I am still stucked. Does anybody know if here is an issue or a work around?

Errors are:

- Warning line 1 Package `auto-pst-pdf` Warning: Creation of `gesamt6-autopp.dvi` failed
- Warning line 1 Package `auto-pst-pdf` Warning: Could not create `gesamt6-pics.pdf`. Auxiliary files are not deleted.

Here is what the problematic code looks like (reduced):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage[notightpage]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\newcommand\surname         {Somefamily}
\newcommand\firstname       {Somename}

\fancyhead[LO,LE]{\begin{textblock*}{80mm}(15mm,16mm)  \Huge{\firstname\ \surname} \end{textblock*}}

\rhead{
\begin{pspicture}(20mm,20mm)% save the space
\psbarcode{MECARD:N:\surname,\ \firstname;ADR:\street,\ \streetnumber,\ \zip,\ \country;TEL:\phoneprefix\phone;EMAIL:\mail;;}{eclevel=H width=1.0 height=1.0}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: If `auto-pst-pdf` does some automagic conversion of pstricks to pdf, then it well may choke on PSTricks in the header. I suggest to pre-generate the QR-code in a `\savebox` and `\usebox` that box in the header.

Answer (score 6):

As Stephan Lemke suggests, here is a working version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,textpos,lipsum,pst-barcode,auto-pst-pdf}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\newcommand\surname{Somefamily}
\newcommand\firstname{Somename}
\newcommand\street{Somestreet}
\newcommand\zip{12345}
\newcommand\streetnumber{42}
\newcommand\country{Noland}
\newcommand\phoneprefix{555}
\newcommand\phone{555-5555}
\newcommand\mail{a@n.l}


% \fancyhead[L]{\begin{textblock*}{80mm}(15mm,16mm)  \Huge{\firstname\ \surname} \end{textblock*}}

\newsavebox{\CARD}

\fancyhead[R]{\usebox{\CARD}}

\setlength{\headheight}{77pt}

\begin{document}

\sbox{\CARD}{%
\begin{pspicture}(20mm,20mm)% save the space
\psbarcode{MECARD:N:\surname,\ \firstname;ADR:\street,\ \streetnumber,\ \zip,\ \country;%
  TEL:\phoneprefix\phone;EMAIL:\mail;;}{eclevel=H width=1.0 height=1.0}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Note that the box must be built after `\begin{document}`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

run it with `xelatex` and everything will be fine:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Bera Serif} 
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pst-barcode,textpos}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\newcommand\surname         {Somefamily}
\newcommand\firstname       {Somename}
\def\street{Street}
\def\streetnumber{12}
\def\zip{12345}
\def\country{USA}
\def\phoneprefix{001}
\def\phone{12346}
\def\mail{abc.org}

\fancyhead[LO,LE]{\begin{textblock*}{80mm}(15mm,16mm)  \Huge{\firstname\ \surname} \end{textblock*}}
\rhead{%
\begin{pspicture}(20mm,20mm)% save the space
\psbarcode{MECARD:N:\surname,\ \firstname;ADR:\street,\ \streetnumber,\ \zip,\ \country;TEL:\phoneprefix\phone;EMAIL:\mail;;}{eclevel=H width=1.0 height=1.0}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

[image]